# Java: ¿Cómo comprimir varios pdf que están en byte[], en un solo archivo .zip?

Tags: java, zip

Estoy trabajando en mi proyecto con angular y spring boot, y quiero descargar varios pdf en un archivo .zip: sin guardar en una ruta, o obtener los pdf desde una ruta:

Esto es lo que tengo ahora:

```
@Override
public Response<ArchivoTO> zipReportePdfCfc(Long codComunicadoObra) {
    Response<ArchivoTO> response = new Response<>("Archivo zip de los pdf de CFC");
    try {
        List<String> archivosPdf = new ArrayList<>();
        List<byte[]> sourcePdf = new ArrayList<>();
        // se obtiene la lista de info para crear el pdf
        List<PdfCFC> responseInfoPdf = listarInfoPdfCfc(codComunicadoObra).getResponse();
        // paso cada item de la lista, para obtener el pdf en byte[]
        responseInfoPdf.forEach((item) -> sourcePdf.add(getByetPdfCFC(item)));

        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        byte[] zip = zipBytes(uuid.toString(), sourcePdf);
        String fileName = "preuba.zip";
        response.set(new ArchivoTO(fileName, null, Base64.encodeBase64String(zip)));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Método que me retorna el pdf en byte[]: (estoy utilizando el TIBCO Jaspersoft)

```
public byte[] getByetPdfCFC(PdfCFC request) {
    Map<String, Object> parameters = generarReporteListPdfCFC(request);
    return new ReporteConformidadObra().generarPDF(parameters);
}
```

Método para comprimir:

```
public static byte[] zipBytes(String filename, List<byte[]> inputs) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inputs.forEach((input) -> {
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
        try {
            entry.setSize(input.length);
            zos.putNextEntry(entry);
            zos.write(input);
            zos.closeEntry();
            zos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El proceso es similar a lo que ya tienes en el código, para guardar varios archivos se debe de llamar al `putNextEntry` por cada archivo a guardar.

```
/**
* Enviamos un Mapa con la clave siendo el nombre del archivo 
*"archivo.txt" y en el valor los byte del archivo.
*/
public static byte[] filesToZip(Map<String, byte[]> mapOfFile) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // Utilizamos try-with-resources para que java se encargue de cerrar 
    // el recurso ZipOutputStream zos al finalizar
    try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> entry : mapOfFile.entrySet()) {
            // Creamos una entrada por cada archivo
            ZipEntry zipEntr = new ZipEntry(entry.getKey());
            byte[] input = entry.getValue();
            zipEntr.setSize(input.length);
            zos.putNextEntry(zipEntr);
            zos.write(input);
            // Cerramos la entrada pero no la variable zos
            zos.closeEntry();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

y para guardar el zip puedes pasar el arreglo de bites y la ruta del archivo por ejemplo fileOutput = "./archivos.zip":

```
    private static void bytesToFile(String fileOutput, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(fileOutput);
        Files.write(path, bytes);
    }
```